# Why doesn't system("cls") work for me on windows?

Tags: c, windows, console, refresh

i have been trying to make my screen refresh every second and i don't understand why it doesn't work.
The countdown works but i want to show only the last "printf" and remove all the other ones befor it.
I'm on window by the way not on linux or Mac

This is what i have tried to do :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int décompte;
    décompte = 120;
    time_t debut, maintenant;
    int tempsrestant;

    time(&debut);
    while(1){
        time(&maintenant);
        tempsrestant = décompte - (maintenant - debut);
        if(tempsrestant == 0){
            printf("vous perdez une de vos trois vies\n"),
            sleep(2);
            break;
        }
        else if(tempsrestant>0){
            printf(" tempsrestant : %d sec",tempsrestant);
            sleep(1);
            system("cls");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the return value from `system()`? You are probably not running it in a CMD.EXE console but somewhere else, like in WSL, where `cls` doesn't exist.

Comment: In support of Ted, `#include <unistd.h>`. In contradiction to Ted, `#include <windows.h>`. Is this some kind of unix emulation environment like Cygwin, MSYS or MSYS2? Those unix emulations emulate unix, and thus use `sh` instead of `cmd` to execute the shell command passed to `system`. (`cls` is a `cmd` builtin.)

Comment: @Rick Mortie, Try: after the `printf(...),` and before the `sleep()`, add `fflush(stdout);`.

Comment: @Rick Mortie, "why it doesn't work." deserve more.  What was seen?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, Good call on `fflush`, but they said the text is output ("The countdown works"). Maybe `system` flushes stdout? What doesn't work is that the screen isn't being cleared by `system("cls")` ("but i want to show only the last "printf" and remove all the other ones befor it").

Comment: @ikegami 1) likely now OP will not reply to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77403449/why-doesnt-systemcls-work-for-me-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment136457519_77403449) posed to the OP.  2) "doesn't work" could imply what you suggest, yet other possibilities and details exist that the OP is best qualified to answer.

Comment: They already explicitly stated what was seen (all the printfs before the last). They literally already answered your question with crystal clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You're including both a unix-specific header file (unistd.h) and a Windows-specific header file (windows.h), so I'm guessing you're operating in a unix emulation environment such as those provided by Cygwin, MSYS and MSYS2.

As unix emulations, they use `sh` instead of `cmd` to execute the shell command passed to `system`. Since `cls` is a `cmd` builtin, this won't work.

Executing `clear` might work.
Executing `cmd /c cls` will work.

Finally, since you're running in a unix emulation, the following might work as well:

```c
printf( "\x1B[H\x1B[2J\x1B[3J" );
fflush( stdout );
```

Comment: You might also suggest a simpler approach: `printf(" tempsrestant : %3d sec\r", tempsrestant); fflush(stdout);` and removing the `system("cls")` call.